# Nginx reverse proxy with dynamic port forwarding

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I'm setting up a reverse proxy on Nginx. I need it to listen to multiple ports. I then would like to hit the exact same port on the backend server. 
Like this: http://frontendserver:9000 -> http://backendserver:9000.

Here's what I thought would work

```
   ## server configuration
    server {

        listen 9000 ;
        listen 9001 ;
        listen 9002 ;
        listen 9003 ;
        listen 9004 ;
        listen 9005 ;
        listen 9006 ;
        listen 9007 ;
        listen 9008 ;
        listen 9009 ;

        server_name frontendserver;

        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
            set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_read_timeout  900;
                proxy_pass_header   Server;
                proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
                proxy_pass         http://backendserver:$server_port/;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
                proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
```

but, it gives me a 502 Bad Gateway error. Any clues why this is, or if there is another way of doing this that would work as explained above?

If i change:

```
proxy_pass         http://backendserver:$server_port/;
```

to

```
proxy_pass         http://backendserver:9000/;
```

it works just fine, that of course defeats the purpose...

Comment: Bad gateway suggests your proxy_pass isn't working properly. Try hard coding in a single server / port, if it works you know where to look.

Comment: I did. If you take a look at the last few lines of the question, i'm changing the variable to port number 9000.

Comment: Ok. If you have the module headers_more installed add something like this in your location, as a debugging aid, then curl the server and see what comes back in the variables.  add_header Z_PORT "$server_port";add_header Z_URL "http://backendserver:$server_port/";

Comment: added add_header Z_URL "backendserver:$server_port/" always ; and got this back: "Z_URL backendserver:9000". So, in other words, i got back what I expect, but it does not work still. Still getting bad gateway. Do I need to escape something maybe when it's in the proxy_pass block?

Comment: Not really sure, try some experimentation perhaps. Also try curling the proxy from the nginx box to test that step.

Comment: Have you tried to set $backendserver "backendserver:$server_port"; and than use proxy_pass http://$backendserver;

Comment: I never useed the following construction: 


        ``` if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
            set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
        }
```
Instead I would purpose declare the following for each port:
    ```server {
listen 9000;
return 301 http://backendserver$server_port;
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement would require the backend servers to be publicly available though, no?

Comment: Are the backend servers in the same network as your nginx? Because you have `proxy` in the tags. As far as I know: it is still not possible to reach "backend" servers behind a corporate http connect proxy (at least with vanilla nginx).

Answer (score 1):

I prepared the directories `/var/www/9000` which only contains one file `index.html` with content of the port corresponding to the path name.

```
server {
        listen 81;
        server_name example.com;
        location ~ /([^/]+) {
                proxy_set_header Host '10.20.30.40';
                proxy_pass http://10.20.30.40:$1/;
        }
}
server {
        listen 9000;
        server_name default;
        root /var/www/9000;
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
}
server {
        listen 9001;
        server_name default;
        root /var/www/9001;
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
}
server {
        listen 9002;
        server_name default;
        root /var/www/9002;
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
}
```

I edited my `hosts` file to contain my server's IP `10.20.30.40 exmaple.com` so I can test without the need on a DNS server.
Then I opened my browser with the address `http://example.com:81/9000`. Content shows corresponding to the port number I supply through the location.

Then I thought it might be a problem with the `$server_name` variable so I made a second test.

```
server {
        listen 82;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host '10.20.30.40';
                proxy_pass http://10.20.30.40:90$server_port/;
        }
}
server {
        listen 9082;
        server_name default;
        root /var/www/9082;
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
}
```

Now I'm opening my browser with `http://example.com:82` and content shows `9082` as expected.

If you supply anything other than the `upstream` group name it gets treated as domain name. That's when you get the `Bad gateway` error.

Here is your solution:
You need to use `map` to translate the requested port to an `upsteam` group and use this in the `proxy_pass`.

```
upstream mycustombackend9082 {
        server 10.20.10.48:9082;
}
map $server_port $backendname {
        82      mycustombackend9082;
}
server {
        listen 82;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header Host '10.20.30.40';
                proxy_pass http://$backendname;
        }
}
server {
        listen 9082;
        server_name default;
        root /var/www/9082;
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html;
}
```

In my case I needed to write `82` into the `map` because I can't open the port two times.
You can see another example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50122194/940009).